# How to comparison datetime with CURRENT_DATE() of DQL

Tags: symfony, date, datetime, doctrine-orm, dql

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        "SELECT b
        FROM AppBundle:Booking b
        AND b.checkin IS NULL
        AND b.bookingDate=CURRENT_DATE()"
    );
```

I want to see the booking of today, but also i want to have the time of booking in bookindDate. So how to comparison datetime bookingDate with CURRENT_DATE() ?

Comment: how is defined the doctrine field `bookingDate`?

Comment: datetime (ex: 2010-04-12 06:01:01)

Comment: Assuming that bookingData is a DateTime column then AND DATE(b.bookingDate) = CURRENT_DATE() should do the trick.

Comment: this not work in DQL (doctrine query language), DATE not exist

Comment: You will need to add DATE as an extension: https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions and http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
        "SELECT b
        FROM AppBundle:Booking b
        AND b.checkin IS NULL
        AND b.bookingDate >= CURRENT_DATE()
        AND b.bookingDate <= CURRENT_DATE()+1"
    );
```

this work for me, too easy ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following DQL query:

```
SELECT b
        FROM AppBundle:Booking b
        AND b.checkin IS NULL
        AND b.bookingDate BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE() AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Check [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#other-expressions) the doc for BETWEEN doctrine2 function

Hope this help

Comment: this not work for me. Maybe becose current date is a date and bookingDate a datetime? i think the way is change format bookingDate, but don't know how do this.

Answer (score 0):

yo can use

```
$date = new DateTime();
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQuery(
        "SELECT b
        FROM AppBundle:Booking b
        AND b.checkin IS NULL
        AND b.bookingDate=". $date->format('Y-m-d')
    );
```

Comment: which dateTime object i must use for this?